# "javascript:void() just renders as "void()"

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

It use to work in the past and on other current websites but updating this site it no longer works. I had a pop up message with woocommerce notices, just saying the item has been added to cart, and with a close button using the javascript:void method. However it no longer works and when I look at the source code it's just out putting as "void(0)" instead of "javascript:void(0)"

I've tried other way such as just using # instead. Nothing works. Box won't close.

```
  <div id="woocommerce-message">
   <div class="close">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closeEmbtn" onclick="closeEm()" 
title="Close Notification"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
</a></div>

<div class="success-cart">
<div class="woocommerce-message">
<?php foreach ( $messages as $message ) : ?>
<?php echo wp_kses_post( $message ); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</div>

<div class="message-cart-buttons">
<a class="button" href="/cart/">View Cart/Checkout</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" onclick="closeEm()">Continue Shopping</a>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function closeEm() {
    document.getElementById("woocommerce-message").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

I'm wanting just a way to close/hide the the "woocommerce-message" div when they click a close button.

--Edit --
I tried a different approach

```
<div class="close">
<a class="closeEmbtn" onclick="closeEm()" href="#" title="Close Notification"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>



<script>
function closeEm() {
var x = document.getElementById("woocommerce-message");

x.style.display = "none";

}
</script>
```

But it's the "onclick=" isn't showing up in the source code either. Is there something in wordpress that could be blocking it?

Comment: First - whenever you have `javascript:` prefix in your code, it would never render to your DOM. What you have in the `href` attribute is a call from a JavaScript function called "void".

To where are you trying to refer from the `a` element?

Comment: even not using javascript:void the onclick isn't rendering either in the source code

Comment: What should it render?

Comment: the full thing <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=closeEm()" title="close"> but all it out puts is <a href="void(0)" title="close">
"javascript" and "onclick" go missing

Comment: As I said. It won’t render the “javascript:” prefix. However, what would you like the void function to yield?

Comment: but all the other sites i've done it with render it as javascript. It needs to render it as javascript:void(0) so the browser know's it's not a proper link. Because when it renders as just 'void(0)' it thinks it's a link and I ended up with a 404 page when it shouldn't link anywhere, I just need it to close a box.

Comment: The “javascript” prefix doesn’t make a difference. It functions as a link cause it’s an a tag

Comment: the script function isn't rendering either. It just prints the code out instead of reading it as code. which makes me think woocomerce is blocking javascript for some reason or there's some missing bracket somewhere

Comment: You can always load JavaScript from an external file

Comment: yeah i'e tried that, but the function won't work because it needs the onclick function in the link which also isn't rendering

Comment: https://mttwood.com/test/imageshare/javacode.jpg 
here's a screenshot of my predicament, hopefully it'll clear somethings up

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a work around with a new script function

```
    <script>
    document.getElementById("close1").onclick = function() { 

        document.getElementById("woocommerce-message").style.display = "none"; 

    } 
    </script>
```

which then doesn't have to rely on javscript:void(0) and onclick in the html.
But I am still curious to know why those elements suddenly disappeared from the output code